# DVR is visible through LAN but invisible through WLAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan, dvr

I Have a DVR device an its IP address is 192.168.1.34, when I'm connected to my internet via a LAN cable I can see the DVR menu in 192.168.1.34 with my browser, but when I'm connected with Wireless I can't see it! what is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DVR port forwarding won't work](http://superuser.com/questions/807073/dvr-port-forwarding-wont-work)

Comment: Can you ping it at least?

Comment: with LAN connected I can ping it, but with wireless it says:reply from 192.166.1.33 destination host unreachable.

Comment: Are you sure it says 192.166.1.33? If it does then your wired and wireless networks are on different subnets and this is your problem.

Comment: oh no, it says 192.168.1.33

Comment: Are you pinging the DVR? In your question it is .34?

Comment: yes, I typed: ping 192.168.1.34 and it said reply from 192.168.1.33 destination host unreachable!

Comment: I've had routers that blocked communication between wireless devices for some reason. Try searching through your router configuration for options that sound like they might be isolating the wireless, or upgrade your router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with `AP Isolation` option in my router, so I went to `router Menu->Wireless->advanced wireless settings` and disabled `AP Isolation`